# Ubuntu document scanner software does not scan images

Tags: hp, scanner

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. And I am using  Hp Multifunction laser printer.
The document scanner software scans texts. But does not scan images.
How can it scan images too?

Comment: And what happens when you try to scan an image?

Comment: The image scan button does not work. When I click on it, it does not respond. But the text scan button works.

Comment: Did you try another scanning software like Simple Scan, or xsane?

Comment: No,I did not try. I should try.

Comment: And what is "The document scanner software"? Is it a specific HP software?

Comment: The software that comes with Ubuntu has one Scan button. And also there is a setting for image and text that is actually switching color and b/w. It works regardless of any hardware.

Comment: Xsane solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: default scanner has preferences, in the drop down to the right of the 'scan' button.